# Deleting selected file from storage and recycle view list

Tags: android

Here is my code for deleting item from recycle view list. First three line of code works to remove the item from recycle view. But when I start my activity again deleted files again comes up as they are not deleted from storage. Can anyone help me to do so? 
How can i remove the selected file from storage as well?

```
 private void deleteItem(int index) {

           recordingArrayList.remove(index);
           notifyItemRemoved(index);
           notifyItemRangeChanged(index,recordingArrayList.size());
//remove from storage
           File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
           String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/IRadio/Audios";
           File file = new File(path);
           file.delete();

        }
```

Comment: you need to give filename too.
File file = new File(path,filename);
boolean isDeleted = file.delete();

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/IRadio/Audios";
File file = new File(path);
file.delete();
if(file.exists()){
    file.getCanonicalFile().delete();
    if(file.exists()){
        getApplicationContext().deleteFile(file.getName());
    } 
}
```

Make sure that your `path` **does exist on the path**.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this. It is working fine now and files from internal storage are also removed by the code.

```
private void deleteItem(int index) {

           recordingArrayList.remove(index);
           notifyItemRemoved(index);
           notifyItemRangeChanged(index, recordingArrayList.size());

           File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
           String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/IRadio/Audios/";
           Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
           File directory = new File(path);
           File[] files = directory.listFiles();
           Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
           String fileName = files[index].getName();
           String recordingUri = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/IRadio/Audios/" + fileName;
           File myfile = new File(recordingUri);
           myfile.delete();
       }
```